# Java ¿Cómo hacer que un programa la terminar vuelva a preguntar?

Tags: java, bucles

Tengo un  programa que es un cajero automático.
Te da las opciones de:

- retirar
- abonar
- consultar saldo
- ningún tramite

Cada que termina una operación regresa al Menú, claro utilicé un `While`.

Hice que al principio preguntará el nombre del usuario, pero ahora quiero que cuándo termine un trámite la persona, vuelva a preguntar el nombre. Pero no me sale....

He aquí mi código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner caja = new Scanner(System.in);

        Cuenta lidy = new Cuenta(600.0);
        Cuenta emma = new Cuenta(390.0);
        Cuenta zared = new Cuenta(200.0);



        String i="lidice";
        String k="emmanuel";
        String y="zared";
        String h;





        h=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"BIENVENIDO al banco <<GCC>> \n ¿Cuál es su nombre?");

       if(i.equals(h)){

      String z;
        double g=0;
        while (g!= 4) {




        z = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("BIENVENIDO LIDY \n Escoge una opción  : \n \n CONSULTAR SALDO-----1 \n ABONAR-----2 \n RETIRAR----3 \n NINGÚN TRAMITE----4");
        g = Double.parseDouble(z);



        if (g == 1) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Escogiste Consultar Saldo es correcto?");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El saldo de lidy es  :" + lidy.getSaldo());
        }

        if (g == 2) {

            String x;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Escogiste  ABONAR es correcto?");

            x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuánto deseas abonar?:   ");
            double c;
            c = Double.parseDouble(x);
            lidy.setAbonar(c);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su daldo es:" + lidy.getSaldo());

        }


        if (g == 3) {

                String s;
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Escogiste  RETIRAR es correcto?");

                s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuánto deseas Retirar?");
                double w;
                w = Double.parseDouble(s);

                if(w>lidy.getSaldo()){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No saldo");
                }
                if(w<lidy.getSaldo()){

                     lidy.setretirar(w);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su saldo es de:" + lidy.getSaldo());
                }
                }
                }

                  }




                 if(k.equals(h)){


      String t;
        double u=0;
        while (u!= 4) {


        t = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("BIENVENIDO Emmanuel \n Escoge una opción  : \n \n CONSULTAR SALDO-----1 \n ABONAR-----2 \n RETIRAR----3 \n NINGÚN TRAMITE----4");
        u = Double.parseDouble(t);



        if (u == 1) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Escogiste Consultar Saldo es correcto?");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El saldo de Emmanuel es  :" + emma.getSaldo());
        }

        if (u == 2) {

            String x;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Escogiste  ABONAR es correcto?");

            x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuánto deseas abonar?:   ");
            double c;
            c = Double.parseDouble(x);
            emma.setAbonar(c);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su daldo es:" + emma.getSaldo());

        }


        if (u == 3) {

                String s;
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Escogiste  RETIRAR es correcto?");

                s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuánto deseas Retirar?");
                double w;
                w = Double.parseDouble(s);

                if(w>emma.getSaldo()){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No saldo");
                }
                if(w<emma.getSaldo()){

                     emma.setretirar(w);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su saldo es de:" + emma.getSaldo());

                }

                }



            }
                 }

         if(y.equals(h)){


      String tt;
        double uu=0;
        while (uu!= 4) {


        tt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("BIENVENIDO Zared \n Escoge una opción  : \n \n CONSULTAR SALDO-----1 \n ABONAR-----2 \n RETIRAR----3 \n NINGÚN TRAMITE----4");
        uu = Double.parseDouble(tt);



        if (uu == 1) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Escogiste Consultar Saldo es correcto?");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El saldo de Zared es  :" + zared.getSaldo());
        }

        if (uu == 2) {

            String x;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Escogiste  ABONAR es correcto?");

            x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuánto deseas abonar?:   ");
            double c;
            c = Double.parseDouble(x);
            zared.setAbonar(c);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su daldo es:" + zared.getSaldo());

        }


        if (uu == 3) {

                String s;
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Escogiste  RETIRAR es correcto?");

                s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuánto deseas Retirar?");
                double w;
                w = Double.parseDouble(s);

                if(w>zared.getSaldo()){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No saldo");
                }
                if(w<zared.getSaldo()){

                     zared.setretirar(w);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su saldo es de:" + zared.getSaldo());
                  }

                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola!, proba poner a partir de ...showInputDialog... todo ese bloque de codigo en un while(salir == false), y una opcion que se llame salir, donde cambies el valor de 'salir' asi podes quebrar el while, si no me explique bien, te doy un ejemplo en una respuesta

Comment: @LcsGrz Perdón no te entendí

Comment: Ya hago la respuesta, me demoro un ratito :D

Comment: muchas graciaaas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno aca esta la solucion que plantee, puse codigo propio para que sea mas resumido el ejemplo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Boolean salir = false;
   while(!salir){
      String accion = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"¿Desea salir?, ingrese SI");
          if(accion.equals("SI")){
              salir = true;
          }
   }
   System.out.println("Hello world!");
}
```

Y dentro del while, deberias poner tu codigo de 'cajero automatico', lo que estaria haciendo mi codigo, es repetir siempre las mismas acciones hasta que el usuario desee salir

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: woooow! muchas muchas grcias